# Wrong characters with accents in alerts and confirms with Phonegap/Cordova

Tags: javascript, utf-8, confirm

I'm trying to display alert and confirm boxes with accents in them but when I run the application what I get are wrong characters, I checked the file encoding and it is UTF-8 and in the index.html I set the utf-8 charset.

Someone has any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use special characters in alert or confirm as they don't take special character directly,instead you can use \u escape sequence in the JavaScript string literal to display these characters.

```
alert("\u00e6\u00f8\u00e5")
```

to get output like this `æøå`

You can find utf-8 equivalent for character you want [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm)

Comment: Than you very much!! Very helpful page.